# database design link 2 tables to 1 that is linked to several

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, composite-key

I currently have **3 main tables** `animal, food and medicine`.

From animal table I get tables:

1. species (cat,dog, bird, fish....)
2. size(small,medium,large, big...)
3. age(puppy, young adult, old...)
4. color (brown, black, gray... )

I want to store useful data of the medicine and food given to animals 
But I do not know how to link these data, is the following approach acceptable or what should I add or remove?

My main question composite keys correctness and the way to retrieve data in queries...

## Animal

```
idAn SEX AGE COMMENT           SPECIES color  HAIR   SIZE
----------------------------------------------------------
1     M   1  without ear         1      1     LONG    1
2     F   2  blue eyed all gray  2      2     short   1
```

## species

```
id name
-------
1  dog
2  cat
3  bird
4  fish
5  reptile
6  mouse  
7  other
```

## age

```
id name
-------
1 puppy
2 young
3 adult
4 old
```

## color

```
id  name
--------
1  black
2  gray
3  gold
4  green
5  red
6  brown
```

## size

```
id  name
--------
1  small
2  medium
3  large
4  big
```

## food

```
id name      label      
-------------------
1  sardine     so 
2  croquettes  dogchauw   
3  chicken     sirw
4  whiskas     whiskas
```

## food_Animal

```
idFood  idAnimal   quantity timesPerDay lastFood    LastWater
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2             1    70gr      3        12-12-12   12-12-12  
3             2    80gr      4        12-11-12   12-11-12
```

and for medicine something like the above.

What could be done or how to use it in MySQL

I was starting with something like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ANIMAL(
    idAn    int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sex     int(2) NOT NULL ,
    age     int(2) NOT NULL ,
    comment varchar(50)  ,                  
        species int(2) NOT NULL , 
    color   int(2) NOT NULL ,
        hair    varchar(50)     ,                   
        size    int(2) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (idAn)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

Comment: Create a view rather than a table - a view is a saved query that can be treated as a table in later queries. Your key indexes are fine - I will make one suggestion which will cut down on the amount of joining you need to do though. Given that each species in the species table is unique, and each color in color, and so on; you can use the `name` field itself as the primary key and drop the `id` column. This will make your foreign keys in `Animal` and `food_Animal` far more readable without having to `join` the look-up tables in.

Comment: Can you please post an example, I think I get an idea of what you are saying, but does that mean I would have a table with only one field (aka colorName, SpeciesName....)?

Comment: That is correct. However, its also possible to combine all your look-ups into a single "master" look-up table with 2 fields - `Entity` (which is the lookup category - Animal, Species, Color etc) and `Name` (the look-up value - dog, cat, black gray etc). An example is probably easier to see: http://pastebin.com/nwWtGDt9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* Create a table with 2 fields, Entity and Name. Primary key is BOTH fields (as we know that Entity->Name will be a unique value) */
CREATE TABLE master_lookup (
  Entity nvarchar(10) not null,
  Name nvarchar(20) not null,
  primary key(Entity, Name)
);

/* Insert some data! */
INSERT INTO master_lookup VALUES 
('Species', 'Dog'),
('Species', 'Cat'), 
('Species', 'Bird'),
('Color', 'Black'),
('Color', 'Brown');

/* Let's have a look... */
SELECT * FROM master_lookup;
 Entity  | Name
----------------
 Species | Dog
 Species | Cat
 Species | Bird
 Color   | Black
 Color   | Brown

/* Et voila. One lookup table, ID numbers need not apply. Let's assume you have a form that will populate the Animal table with a list of species for the user to pick from. The source of the list is easy: */
SELECT Name FROM master_lookup WHERE Entity = 'Species';

/* Your INSERT query into Animal will look like this (let's say they're entering a small brown long-haired dog): */
INSERT INTO Animal ('M', 11, 'a comment', 'Dog', 'Brown', 'Long', 'Small');

/* And now when you SELECT from the animal table... */
SELECT * FROM Animal

idAn SEX AGE COMMENT           SPECIES color  HAIR   SIZE
----------------------------------------------------------
1     M   11  a comment         Dog    Brown  Long   Small

/* Look ma! No joins! Which means your query is much simpler and much faster! Yay! */
```